# 'React' was used before it was defined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app, eslint

I am working with create-react-app + typescript + eslint application and during build have such error:

```
Line 1:8:  'React' was used before it was defined  @typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define
```

Code in my component starts with:

```
import React from "react";
```

Eslint settings:

```js
module.exports = {
  parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 2020,
    sourceType: "module",
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true
    }
  },
  settings: {
    react: {
      version: "detect"
    }
  },
  extends: [
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "prettier/@typescript-eslint",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended"
  ],
  rules: {
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types": 0,
    "@typescript-eslint/triple-slash-reference": 0,
    "no-use-before-define": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define": "off"
  },
};
```

Some part of package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.1.0",
  "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.1.0",
  "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
  "eslint": "^6.6.0",
  "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.1.0",
  "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.11.0",
  "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.2",
  "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.3",
  "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.20.0",
  "prettier": "^2.0.5",
  "start-server-and-test": "^1.11.3"
},
"dependencies": {
  ...
  "react-scripts": "3.4.3",
  ...
}
```

**I tried:**

- Read https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/2502
- Disable @typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define and no-use-before-define in .eslintrc.js
- Actually I tried to delete .eslintrc.js at all, but had the same error.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

The bug occurs due to mismatch of `@typescript-eslint` versions in react-scripts and your local `package.json` - [GitHub issue](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/2540)

You can downgrade the packages until `react-scripts` updates their version.

```json
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.0.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.0.1",
```

**EDIT 2020-09-14**

It seems the bug is not related to `react-scripts` version of `@typescript-eslint` since multiple people reported the same bug without using `react-scripts`.

Anyway, the workaround remains the same - downgrade to the working version of `@typescript-eslint` until the fix is available.

**EDIT 2020-10-24**

`react-scripts@4.0.0` has been published with updated `@typescript-eslint`. Using the newest version should solve the issue.

**EDIT 2020-11-04**

If after upgrading the packages the error is still there, most probably your eslint config uses the wrong rule. Check out [Igor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64024916/3872362) to fix it.

Comment: did not worked for me. "react": "^16.13.1", "typescript": "~3.7.2",     "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.0.1", "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.0.1". Same error as the post.

Comment: Have you tried deleting `node_modules` and reinstalling the packages?

Comment: i did but the warning keeps there.

Comment: In your `package.json` specify `typescript-eslint` version without caret `^` as it will install the latest minor version, not `4.0.1`.

Comment: Upgrading `react-scripts` to v4.0.0 (`next` as of this writing) fixes this. `npm i react-scripts@next`.

Comment: Can confirm that using react-scripts@next and the latest typescript-eslint deps resolves the issue

Comment: It worked for me only after downgrading to the versions specified ( without caret obviously)

Comment: check "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin" at yarn.lock or package-lock.json, if other lib uses other version, sync your version

Answer (score 324):

From the [official documentation](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-use-before-define/#how-to-use).

```
"rules": {
  // note you must disable the base rule as it can report incorrect errors
  "no-use-before-define": "off",
  "@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define": ["error"]
}
```

Comment: See also this recommendation from a maintainer of typescript-eslint https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/2540#issuecomment-692505191

Comment: Doesn't work. I am using `@typescript-eslint` 4.22.

Comment: The rules settings as mentioned above, worked for me. Turn off the first rule which is buggy and turn on the second which is works fine.

Comment: Adding just `"no-use-before-define": "off",` to my `.eslintrc.json` rules did it for me.

Comment: @Praym first rule is not buggy. *Original* ESLint rules are valid for JS only even though many work with TS with no issues. You should switch off JS rule before using a **matching** TS rule. https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/README.md#supported-rules

Answer (score 15):

If you are only getting this error for `.js` files, make sure `@typescript-eslint/parser` is being used exclusively on Typescript files.

**.eslintrc.json** (abbreviated)

```js
{
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
      "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint"],
      "rules": {
        "no-use-before-define": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define": ["error"],
      },
    }
  ],
  // WRONG: Do not use @typescript-eslint/parser on JS files
  // "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "plugins": [
    "react",
    // "@typescript-eslint"
  ],
}
```

Comment: I had to put this in overrides:
"parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
"plugins": ["@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin"],

Answer (score 10):

That is how I resolved my problem.

1. First of all, go to the node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js and change cache to false, because this will help you to understand what works and what is not then you changing eslint file. [I found it here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9007#issuecomment-628601097)

```
 cache: true, // You can set it to false
 formatter: require.resolve('react-dev-utils/eslintFormatter'),
```

2. Add ENV varialbe to .env file. [More info](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/setting-up-your-editor/#experimental-extending-the-eslint-config)

```
 EXTEND_ESLINT=true
```

3. From now CRA will have to use your local eslint for linting during your build and we have control to disable some rules, in my case in .eslintrc:

```
rules: {
    "@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define": "off"
},
```

Comment: Careful on modifying it directly as it'd get overwritten by a yarn/npm install. I'd recommend to do the webpack.config.js modification through craco: https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco

Answer (score 7):

I landed on this page after I started getting issues with a Gatsby project that was using Typescript and an ESLint config that extended `eslint-config-airbnb-typescript`. In addition to OP's error, ESLint was also giving errors on various rules not being defined, like `Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/no-redeclare' was not found.` and a few others.

The underlying problem ended up being that Gatsby was using fairly old versions of both `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin` and `@typescript-eslint/parser`. Forcing `yarn` to install only up-to-date versions solved the issue:

```json
// package.json
"resolutions": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.4.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.4.0"
}
```

Comment: This saved me thanks. After doing some digging it seems like gatsby installs both of those libs with ^2.24.0 version which is super old and they get used for some reason. So frustrating that on the docs it says, just make your own .eslintrc and all good, and then they include their own parser and ruleset that gets used.

Answer (score 5):

I got this error from the `airbnb-base` ruleset in a typescript project. Also extending [`airbnb-typescript`](https://github.com/iamturns/eslint-config-airbnb-typescript) (that has the correct rules for typescript) resolved the issue.

Answer (score 4):

My fix for that:
Use eslint 6 as react-scripts is using
Force react scripts to use newer @typescript-eslint packages as the rest of the repo.
I'm using [selective resolution](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/#toc-how-to-use-it) here

```
  "resolutions": {
    "**/react-scripts/**/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.4.1",
    "**/react-scripts/**/@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.4.1"
  }
```

`@typescript-eslint` 4.x does still support es6

Comment: for me, it wasn't just react-scripts that kept an outdated version of `@typescript-eslint` as a dependency. i found out the other culprits with `yarn list @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin @typescript-eslint/parser`

Answer (score 3):

I just wanted to add that for me, I did the following.

1. Removed all eslint related dependencies from `package.json` if they were already included in `package-lock.json` by react-scripts (for me that was all of them)
2. Deleted my `node_modules` folder, and `package-lock.json` file
3. Ran `npm install`

After completing those steps I finally got that error to go away. I prefer removing the dependencies to downgrading them since this will help avoid the same issue happening again in the future.

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me - thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This has been resolved in 4.4.0. Upgrade these dependencies to version 4.4.0

**Update:** This may work for some use cases. This resolved my issue.

```
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.4.0",
"@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.4.0",
```

Comment: it's not. I tested 4.4.0 and 4.4.1

Comment: This worked for me when I set these within `"resolutions"` inside my `package.json`.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding import/resolver to your `Eslint` settings:

```
  "settings": {
    "react": { "version": "detect" },
    "import/resolver": { "typescript": {} }
  }
```

Maybe you will need to install it too:

```
$ yarn add -D eslint-import-resolver-typescript
```

If that doesn't work, you could change this rule

```
"@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define": "off"
```

like this:

```
"no-use-before-define": "off"
```

Answer (score 1):

It is an issue present in ESLINT.

The way I resolve is to add the **following lines to the ESLINT/rules**:

"no-use-before-define": [0],
"@ typescript-eslint / no-use-before-define": [1],

Answer (score 1):

If you use Create React App. Getting the latest version of `react-scripts` fixed this issue for me. Currently: `4.0.3`

```
// Get this specific version:
npm uninstall react-scripts
npm install react-scripts@4.0.3

// Get latest version:
npm uninstall react-scripts
npm install react-scripts
```

Answer (score 0):

*(not enough rep to comment)*

@sashko's workaround seems to work - deleting `node_modules` was necessary as well.

One thing I missed was the caret in `"^4.0.1"`. The version needs to be fixed *without* the caret `^`, which seems to be the issue that @Rolly is having. Make sure it's `4.0.1`.

Only a workaround until `react-scripts` updates to v4 (I'm using `create-react-app`)

Answer (score 0):

deleting the `node_modules` folder and reinstalling it worked for me. I'm using `yarn` as package manager.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted packages `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin` and `@typescript-eslint/parser` from my `package.json`,
deleted `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`,
reinstalled packages: `npm install`
The error disappeared.

**UPDATE**

After that create-react-app uses their own `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin` module which is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

### This Answer worked for me in a react-native project(airbnb style guide)

1. Extend your rules with `airbnb-typescript` inside the  `.eslintrc.json`

```
"extends": {
  "airbnb-typescript"
}
```

2. Press ctrl+shift+p *or* cmd+shift+p >Reload window (or simply close and re-open vscode)

Answer (score -3):

Try using [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/) instead of NPM (make sure to remove your `node_modules` in between).

This worked for me.