# "'React' was used before it was defined." eslint warning

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

Similar question to [this post on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63818415/react-was-used-before-it-was-defined) but I cannot seem to get rid of this warning after trying everything I could find on the internet. [Github Issue.](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/2502)

```
 Line 1:8:  'React' was used before it was defined  @typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define
```

I've tried adding these to the rules in `.eslintrc.json` but neither seem to remove the warning.

```
 "no-use-before-define": "off",
 "@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define": "off"

 "no-use-before-define": [0],
 "@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define": [1]
```

This issue doesn't exist on my other projects. I've tried copying `package.json` and `.eslintrc.json` from the other projects and re-installing `node_modules`, however it still persists.

Does anyone have any other suggestions to resolve the warning? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where's the code that producing this error?

Comment: You can try downgrading `@typescript-eslint` version as suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/a/63862578/3872362

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['React' was used before it was defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63818415/react-was-used-before-it-was-defined)

Answer (score 6):

that is because:

> This is a pretty common thing because TypeScript adds new features that ESLint doesn't know about.
> The first step is to check our list of "extension" rules here. An extension rule is simply a rule which extends the base ESLint rules to support TypeScript syntax. If you find it in there, give it a go to see if it works for you. You can configure it by disabling the base rule, and turning on the extension rule.

So pls try to write that rules in your `.eslintrc.json`:

```
   "no-use-before-define": "off",
   "@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define": ["error"],
```

related link:

https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-use-before-define.md

https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/docs/getting-started/linting/FAQ.md#i-am-using-a-rule-from-eslint-core-and-it-doesnt-work-correctly-with-typescript-code