# Eslint error causing create-react-app failed to compile

Tags: reactjs, eslint, eslintrc, typescript-eslint

I am building a website using `create-react-app` and have just installed `eslint` to it.

For some reason what was supposed to be shown as eslint warnings are showing up as errors and causing `npm run start` to fail.

How can I bypass this issue and have them shown as warnings like before ?

**My .eslintrc.js**

```
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es6: true,
    jest: true,
  },
  extends: [
    'airbnb-typescript',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    'prettier/react',
    'prettier/@typescript-eslint',
    'plugin:prettier/recommended',
  ],
  globals: {
    Atomics: 'readonly',
    SharedArrayBuffer: 'readonly',
  },
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
    },
    ecmaVersion: 2018,
    sourceType: 'module',
    project: './tsconfig.json',
  },
  plugins: ['react', '@typescript-eslint'],
  rules: {
    'class-methods-use-this': 'off',
    'additional-rule': 'warn',
  },
  ignorePatterns: ['**/node_modules/*', '**/build/*', 'config-overrides.js'],
};
```

**My package.json**

````
  "name": "device-protection-renewal-web",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.15",
    "@types/node": "^12.19.3",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.55",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.9",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "i18next": "^19.8.3",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^2.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-i18next": "^11.7.3",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all",
      "ie >= 9"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version",
      "ie >= 9"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions": "^7.12.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.6.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.6.1",
    "eslint": "^7.11.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^9.0.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.20.6",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.1.0",
    "prettier": "^2.1.2",
    "typescript": "^4.0.5"
  }
}```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUKcz.png
````

Answer (score 5):

I assume that you have installed ESLint using `npm install eslint --save-dev` and defined a default configuration with `node_modules/.bin/eslint --init` answering the questions in the prompt.

I noticed that in your `.eslintrc.js` file, the ESLint settings is missing in the extends option:

```
extends: [
    'eslint:recommended',
    'airbnb-typescript',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    'prettier/react',
    'prettier/@typescript-eslint',
    'plugin:prettier/recommended',
  ],
```

Also in the `package.json` is recommended ESLint to have its own script that you run using `npm run lint` and use it combined with a eslint-plugin in your favorite code editor:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    // ...
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
}
```

Probably you will build your application at some point, so you should create a `.eslintignore` file and inside of it add `build` since files in the build directory also get checked by default when the command is ran.

Source: https://fullstackopen.com/en/part3/validation_and_es_lint#lint

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have done all the above but still getting ```failed to compile``` with lots of eslint errors when running ```npm run start```

Comment: I am getting something like this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/15jLzUyCFOKFWK2ZqQIQlmJUteEfzIsOF/view?usp=sharing

Which I think it's strange because I am used to seeing them as warnings instead of errors

Comment: Hi again @liam. Reading the error message log you provided I found a similar problem as yours at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63818415/react-was-used-before-it-was-defined.

There is a solution from Igor that seems worked for several people. Could you kindly check it out?

Comment: Hello again. I have tried the above solution, it got rid of the error ```'React' was used before it was defined```, but the rest of the errors still persists. I am wondering if this may be related to the ```react-scripts``` version I am using. This repo is using ```4.0.0```, and my other repo is using ```3.4.3``` with the same eslint versions and is compiling just fine.

Comment: I have just downgraded my ```react-scripts``` to ```3.4.3``` and am able to compile now. I think I might stick with this version for now.

Comment: faced similar situation where manually installing eslint is causing failure in compilation. 
Downgrading to 3.4.3 did the trick

Answer (score 0):

This part in your `package.json` is unnecessary; since you have an eslint config file, it should be moved to `.eslintrc.js`.

```
"eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
}
```

Which would then turn into this:

```
extends: [
    'react-app',
    'react-app/jest',
    'airbnb-typescript',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    'prettier/react',
    'prettier/@typescript-eslint',
    'plugin:prettier/recommended'
]
```

However; in the latest versions of the `eslint-config-react-app` plugin at this time `(7.31.11)`, I'm getting a jest plugin conflict error with a project that worked prior to updating unless I remove `react-app/jest` from my eslint configs `extends` section.

Which is how I ended up here, currently trying to find out what caused this.

Update: So my issue was caused because `eslint-config-react-app` depends on `eslint-plugin-jest^25.7.0` and I was using the latest `eslint-plugin-jest^27.1.6`. I removed my `package.json`'s dependency and will use the version included with `eslint-config-react-app` so there aren't any conflicts there, but if I need features of the newer plugin version, a quick `npm i -D` on it, changing eslint configuration from automatic to manual and specifying the path to the local `node_modules` version and `.eslintrc.js` should work as well; aside from any conflicts with the config plugin.