# no-use-before-define has no effect when extending eslint-config-react-app

Tags: javascript, eslint

I am trying to configure eslint to use `eslint-config-react-app` as a base and specify a few specific rules on top of that. One of those rules is `no-use-before-define`, and I am trying this out on the following trivial example to check whether the rule is working as desired:

```js
const a = () => {
    b();
};
const b = () => {};
a();
```

If I set up my .eslintrc.json like this, then the rule works as expected:

```json
{
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 2020
    },
    "rules": {
        "no-use-before-define": "error"
    }
}
```

```
2:5  error  'b' was used before it was defined  no-use-before-define
```

However, if I include `"extends": "react-app"`, no eslint errors are found:

```json
{
    "extends": "react-app",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 2020
    },
    "rules": {
        "no-use-before-define": "error"
    }
}
```

If I intentionally introduce a change that would cause another eslint violation - e.g. remove the `a();` a the end, then *that* is found, but not the `no-use-before-define` violation:

```
  1:7  warning  'a' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
```

Intuitively, I would expect any rules in .eslintrc.json to be applied *on top of* the config indicated in `"extends"`, but it seems like that's not what's happening.

What am I misunderstanding here? Is there a way to extend `eslint-config-react-app` *and* have the `no-use-before-define` rule work correctly?

Comment: Maybe a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/65159131/2837427
Also check for the versions https://stackoverflow.com/a/64311559/2837427

Comment: Thank you, but that is not the issue I'm having. My issue is the _lack_ of an error when I expect to see one. I'm also not using @typescript-eslint afaik.

Comment: @typescript-eslint is present in peerDependencies though https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/eslint-config-react-app/package.json#L21

Comment: Also for `no-use-before-define` https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/7325

Comment: @hendrixchord That github issue was not the same as mine (it was the opposite), but it did give me the hint I needed in order to solve this, so thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like I've figured it out.

It seems I was overriding the *severity* of the rule, but not the options, which were set to `{ "functions": false, "variables": false, "classes": false }`. So it remained in a configuration where eslint would only find an issue in the case of variables being used after their declaration *in the same scope*.

Specifying the options explicitly yields the desired behavior:

```
"no-use-before-define": ["error", { "functions": true, "variables": true }]
```

Looks like this also works for reverting back to the eslint default options for this rule:

```
"no-use-before-define": ["error", {}]
```