# Unable to resolve path to module (import/no-unresolved) in eslint

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I'm having mix codebase of Typescript and Javascript with monorepo configuration with Lerna in create-react-app. I'm importing TS files in my JS files with tsconfig.json setup, but getting an error with eslint.

Currently, my `.eslintrc.json` looks like this, I've newly added the `settings` here, but it didn't seem to work

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es2021": true,
    "jest": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "airbnb",
    "prettier",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended",
    "plugin:import/typescript"
  ],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    },
    "ecmaVersion": 12,
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "plugins": ["react", "prettier"],
  "rules": {
    "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off",
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": [
      1,
      { "extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"] }
    ],
    "prettier/prettier": "error",
    "jsx-a11y/click-events-have-key-events": "off",
    "import/no-extraneous-dependencies": ["error", { "devDependencies": true }],
    "react/function-component-definition": [
      2,
      {
        "unnamedComponents": "arrow-function"
      }
    ],
    "import/no-relative-packages": "off"
  },
  "ignorePatterns": ["config-overrides.js", "*.json", "*.md", "*.css"],
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "typescript": true,
      "node": true
    },
    "import/parsers": {
      "@typescript-eslint/parser": [".ts", ".tsx"]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try adding

`@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin, @typescript-eslint/parser` plugins

update .eslintrc.json

```
  ... 
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "project": "tsconfig.json",
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "plugins": ["eslint-plugin-import", "@typescript-eslint", "react", "react-hooks", "react-native", "jsx-a11y"],
  "settings": {
    "import/extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"],
    "import/parsers": {
      "@typescript-eslint/parser": [".ts", ".tsx"]
    },
    "import/resolver": {
      "node": {
        "extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"],
        "moduleDirectory": ["node_modules", "src/"]
      }
    }
  },
  ...
```

Comment: it is working except for an error I'm getting now - 
"'React' was used before it was defined  no-use-before-define"

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63818415/react-was-used-before-it-was-defined/64024916#64024916 disable `"no-use-before-define": "off"`

Comment: thanks, figured it out, could you also provide me what should be the pure react TS configuration for ESLint?